# How to make transparent borders to cut or cover objects with transparent blocks (EEVEE)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, render-border

I want to be able to use transparent borders that can cover objects from the camera and match the transparent background, Similar to images where there is a layout of boxes and every object can be scaled and moved freely inside and areas that leave the box are cut out

[image: image example, how do I replicate this?]

Here is my scene, I've used monkey's in place of the actual characters I plan to use, I want to know what methods I can use to simply cut or cover any areas that leave the boxes

[image: basically portals on a transparent wall]

I've tried to use several transparent cubes and Boolean modifiers but they are not always accurate or efficient, since the Boolean object need to be smaller than the mesh in order to cut from it, and using it with a rigged humanoid mesh bring worse results.

[image]

Comment: This looks like something to do by compositing multiple render layers together.

Comment: use Chris' solution, just shift each head on the Y axis and use several holdout objects

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of thing with "holdout".

You can set this check here:

[image]

If you model frames like this (blue) - maybe solidify modifier can help you - and give it a "track to" object constraint to the camera.

[image]

Then you will get:

[image]